# Google+ sharing title

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I implement Google+ sharing in my app as follows:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
```

**Detail.m**

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
    [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@""];
    [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Testing" description:@"Testing desc" thumbnailURL:ImageURL];

       [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"1"];

    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:itemURL]];

    [shareBuilder open];
```

**But I can share the URL only.**

Title, Description & Image are not shown on Google+.

Answer (score 0):

> Method [setUrlToShare] override the data you writed before in [setTitle ...]
>
> [setUrlToShare]-parse title,desciption and thumbnail from URL.
> Or use one method of them,or try first call [setUrlToShare],and override them by [setTitle].